# How do I access data in "int20_t"?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, integer

I got a lot of memory pieces in 512 bits. I need to write numbers in 20 bits.

For example:

```
// a piece of 512 bits memory
void *p = malloc(64);

struct Coords {
  int20_t x, y;
};

// usage
Coords *pcoord = (Coords *)p;

for (int i = 0; i < 512 / 40/*sizeof(Coords)*/; ++i) {
  pcoord[i].x = i;
  pcoord[i].y = 2 * i;
}
```

How to implement **int20_t** ?

**I need exactly 20 bits for an integer. The numbers must be continuous.**
( [0]  to [19] for the first Coords.x;
[20] to [39] for the first Coords.y;
...
There are 12 pairs of Coords with 480 bits and 32 bits for the pad.)

Comment: `int x : 20; int y : 20`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ 2.5 bytes (20-bit) integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725325/c-2-5-bytes-20-bit-integer)

Comment: For example, as a custom class: `class int20_t { public: int20_t() { /* C-tor*/ } int20_t& operator +(const int20_t&); /* other operators etc...*/ private: int8_t data[3]; };`

Comment: Do you want to pass this data type between C and C++ code? If not, please pick the language you want to use and remove the unrelated language tags.

Comment: So the use case is to write numbers of 20 bits size to a buffer without any padding? You wrote "I got a lot of memory pieces in 512 *bits*", but `malloc(512) allocates 512 *bytes*`. Do you mean bits or bytes? Please [edit] your question and explain the background. What is the use case for this data format? What about the order of the bits? Assuming you have `uint8_t *buf;` and the first 20 bits are in `buf[0]`, `buf[1]` and `buf[2] & 0xF0u`. Is the most significant bit `buf[0] & 0x80u`? and the least significant bit `buf[2] & 0x10u`? And is the next MSB in `buf[2] & 0x08u`?

Comment: @SergeRoussak: That won't work. Classes are aligned at byte boundaries, if not bigger.

Comment: @MSalters, it's a particulars. There are a lot of ways to solve or workaround this. For example, a constructor taking the pointer may be used to initialize the `int20_t` value. And I think, a custom classes using is more reliable and portable than tricks with memory.

Comment: @SergeRoussak: You can't get a pointer to a half-byte

Comment: @MSalters, nobody prevents to use second parameter designating the offset within the byte.

Comment: @SergeRoussak: Well, if you don't believe me, try to write that class. Make sure to fit 24 objects in 480 bits, as requested

Comment: @MSalters, once again: there are many ways to implement requested feature. One more example: the custom class might hold a pointer to the underlying memory and the shift within of it (as well as define all required operations on this 20-bit value). So, it is not needed to fit these objects in 480 bits, take care about theirs alignment etc. The main idea of my message: it's more convenient to wrap this functionality into a class than to do something with this memory directly.

Comment: What exotic system is this for? In case it is _not_ for an exotic system, then simply don't declare a `int20_t`, because it's the wrong solution to a bad specification. Simply use a `int32_t` and mask out relevant parts, if you must. In C++ there's also a bitfield container class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `int20_t` is only available on very specific hardware with 20 bit registers. You do not need this type to handle your data, you can either use plain `int` to store the coordinates or possibly use bit-fields but it does not seems necessary.

The main issue is the conversion from the external representation (12 packed pairs of 20 bit values in a 512 bit block) to a more manageable in memory representation as an array of structures, and possibly the other way around.

To handle this conversion, you must specify precisely how the bits are packed in the 64 byte block. Each value will be split in 3 parts, the order of these bytes and bits inside the last byte bytes must be specified.

Here is an example where values are stored in big endian format with the third byte containing the low order bits of `x` in its high order bits and the high order bits of `y` in its low order bits:

```
struct Coords {
    int x, y;
};

void load_coords(struct Coords *a, const unsigned char *p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        a->x = (p[0] << 12) + (p[1] << 4) + (p[2] >> 4);
        a->y = ((p[2] & 15) << 16) + (p[3] << 8) + p[4];
        p += 5;
        a++;
    }
}

void store_coords(unsigned char *p, const struct Coords *a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        p[0] = a->x >> 12;
        p[1] = a->x >> 4;
        p[2] = (a->x << 4) | ((a->y >> 16) & 15);
        p[3] = a->y >> 8;
        p[4] = a->y;
        p += 5;
        a++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask what is "& 15" for?

Comment: `p[2] & 15` extracts the 4 least significant bits of the byte. You could also write `p[2] & 0x0F` to make this more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. In `int20_t x, y;`, you would require fractional alignment (unless you have 10 bits hardware somehow).

The rationale is that `&y` must be an `int20_t*`, convertable to `void*`.

You can create a wrapper type for the whole 480 bits, with an `operator[]`.

Comment: I won't change the alignment. Is there a way to easily access to each 20 bit?

Comment: @Xingx1: Not really. You'd need to `memcpy` the 24 bits into a `std::int_32_t`, and use bit shifts & masking to extract the 20 bits you want.